# Magento Flash + XML frontend

Tags: xml, flash, magento, frontend

I'm working on a Flash frontend for a Magento powered store. This frontend will be an alternative to the HTML shop so it will sit in a subdirectory and use the same Magento installation as the main HTML site.

The Flash application will get the data from dynamic XML files. It needs to get almost everything as the HTML site (categories, products, cart, etc).

I want this to be a Magento module that can be installed on an already existing Magento installation. I would like to use the Block classes available in Magneto's core code as they already provide a lot of the functionality needed.

What steps would you take in order to achieve this? Do you know any examples or articles related to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What your trying to do isn't necessarily a plugin, since you are trying to override the HTML output of the site. This kind of modification would probably be best created as a new design or template, overriding all HTML w/ XML as you go. Then you can include the SWF files as part of the skin, and users will be able to install your new frontend by downloading the new design/template.

Comment: The thing is that I want to have both the HTML frontend and also the Flash frontend. By default the HTML frontend is loaded but I need to provide a way for the user to switch to the Flash shop. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you only need one, the user can change to your design in the admin panel at any time. If you want to have them both simultaneously, look at creating another "store" inside Magento and then do the above with one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this http://www.de-la-le.com (it is Magento based)
This can be most probably achieved right now using the following extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/specs/1730/mammoth_webservices-0-3-0-tgz
which allows to do all front-end cart handling via API.

Comment: Thanks for this! Didn't manage to find any documentation for the Mammoth extension... have you worked with this?

Comment: I haven't worked with this extension but try following the link to it and the author might have some documentation available. As de-la-le.com looks great i assume it is useful :)